# What are the methods of dynamic hashing?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, hash

I'm new to this topic and I have a question. Google does not help, finds only linear hashing and dynamic resizing. What other methods exist? Or I something not so understand?

Comment: Do you mean [Dynamic perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing) ? If yes, can you be more specific about what it is you don't understand ?

Comment: No, I mean hash methods with a dynamic hash table